# Https post request using curl : Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, curl, https

I am trying to execute a https post request using curl. When I execute this request, I am neither getting any response nor any error or exception. Help or any clue about what's going wrong here is appreciated. Thanks.

curl command line format :

```
    curl -X POST \
-F 'image=@filename.png;type=image/png' \
-F 'svgz=@filename.svgz;type=image/svg+xml' \
-F 'json={ 
    "text" : "Hello world!",
    "templateid" : "0010",
    "timestamp" : "1342683312", 
    "location" : [ 37.7793, -122.4192 ],
    "facebook" :
    {
        "id": "738124695",
        "access_token": "<VALID_USER_FACEBOOK_TOKEN_WITH_PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSIONS",
        "expiration_date": "1342683312"                
    }
};type=application/json' \
https://sample.com/api/posts
```

Facebook posting code :

```
public static void uploadToFB() {
    HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://sample.com/api/posts");
    httpost.addHeader("image", "filename.png");
    httpost.addHeader("svgz", "filename.svgz");
    httpost.addHeader("type", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject facebook = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray location = new JSONArray();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        data.put("text","Hello world!");
        data.put("templateid","0010");
        data.put("timestamp","2012-07-08 09:00:45.312195368+00:00");

        location.put(37.7793);
        location.put( -122.4192);
        data.put("location", location);
        facebook.put("id", "738124695");
        facebook.put("access_token", "AAADdF92joPABAKmRojBuXZAZAP"+
            "qF8ZAxM2bM"+
             "UnIErUSYZB85y5vIHAZDZD");
        facebook.put("expiration_date", "2013-07-07T 22:00:00Z");
        data.put("facebook", facebook);

        System.out.println(" ---- data ----- "+data);

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(data.toString());
        httpost.setEntity(stringEntity);
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpost);
            System.out.println(" --- response --- "+response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release
            if(entity != null) {
                // A Simple Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                System.out.println(" ---- result ---- "+result);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It was an untrusted network, so, for that I did something like below as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) link.

```
private static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hard time I got solution for my problem. Now, using `MultipartEntity`, I am able to send data to server like below.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://sample.com/api/posts");
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile1 = new FileBody(new File("file.png"), "image/png");
    mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile1);

    ContentBody cbFile2 = new FileBody(new File("file.svg"), "image/svg+xml");
    mpEntity.addPart("svgz", cbFile2);

    ContentBody cbFile3 = new StringBody(getJsonData().toString(), "application/json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    mpEntity.addPart("json", cbFile3);

    httpost.setEntity(mpEntity);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader inPost = null;


    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(mURL);

            httpost.setHeader("Accept","*/*");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testkey1", "myvalue1"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testkey2", "myvalue2"));


            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inPost = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            String linePost = "";
            String NLPOST = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((linePost = inPost.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(linePost + NLPOST);
            }
            inPost.close();
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }


        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

also more on this link..
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/

Comment: Thank u for your efffort. I got solution for my problem